# How can I time PHP's microtime itself?

Tags: php, performance, timer

I tend to check the speed of my PHP stuff using the usual approach.

```
<?php  
$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);  
/*
    some code here that I want to time 
*/  
$timer_end = microtime(TRUE);  
echo($timer_end - $timer_start);  
exit();  
?>
```

How can I time how much time is used by the two calls of PHP's *microtime* function itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is: ***“You can't – meaning: your timing result will not 100% exact!”***.

Fact is, logic already implies that it is not really possible time *"how much time is used by the two calls of PHP's microtime function itself"* and get a result that's 100% exact, as you'll always end up including (at least) one variable assignment in your timing.

So, this is the closest you'll get:

```
  <?php
  // start the timer
  $timer_start = microtime(TRUE);
  // Call microtime once (we want to calculate time wasted by microtime 2 calls)
  microtime(TRUE);
  // stop the timer and return the result
  echo(((microtime(TRUE) - $timer_start)*1000).' microseconds');
  exit();
  ?>
```

If you look at the code above, you'll notice I did not use `$timer_end = microtime(TRUE);` as that would be wasting time on a variable assignment which can be avoided by bluntly taking the return value of that `microtime` call and substracting the starting time: `(microtime(TRUE) - $timer_start)`.

That's great, but **there is no way to make PHP remember the starting time without assigning it to a variable**, meaning: you'll always be doing some kind of `$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);` where you can't avoid initializing the `$timer_start` variable – which wastes time. Wasted time that is included in our final result. There's no way to get around that.

To explain what I mean: We can avoid the variable assignment at the end of the timing sequence by replacing

```
$timer_end = microtime(TRUE);  
echo($timer_end - $timer_start);
```

with

```
echo(microtime(TRUE) - $timer_start);
```

but we can't do the same for `$timer_start = microtime(TRUE);`.

No matter how we try to approach the problem, we'll always end up doing the following:

1. call `microtime(TRUE)`
2. waste time initializing `$timer_start` with the return value of `microtime(TRUE)` (see *“1.”*),
3. call `microtime(TRUE)` doing nothing else,
4. call `microtime(TRUE)` and substract the starting time (see *“2.”*) from it.

You need point **“2.”** to remember the starting time. You can't skip that variable assignment in any way or work around the problem. Whatever you do, you'll **always** be including a variable assignment in your timing result. And to make it worse: you'll never know how much time was wasted during that variable assignment, making your result incorrect (better: not 100% correct).

To help you understand it… in case of the question and the code I provided at the start of this answer, the problem can be visualized as:

[image: visualization]

Explaining it: `microtime` will know the exact time **before** it returns it's value – so we won't get an exact value returned (but pretty close). Then the returned value needs to be assigned to a variable so we can remember it – which takes more time which is not related to what we actually want to time.

Wrapping it up: you can get close, but your return value will never be 100% correct. If you've understood what I explained above, you'll now know that, whatever you're timing in PHP, will always include the time wasted on that one “remember-start-time” variable initialization.

Even if you would create a script containing nothing but `<?php microtime(); microtime(); ?>` and use an external program… you would notice you're doing nothing else but shifting the problem to the external program. The external program will have the same problem the visualization shows, because the external program will have to remember the starting-time by initializing a variable too, which means the external program will not be able to correctly time it either.

In the end, my question ended up to be more of a brain-teaser to think about the logic behind timing programs, loops, and functions using PHP as an example. As my answer explains it doesn't matter what coding language you use, you'll always hit the same issue.

I'll leave it up to you to decide if that “wasted time” that's included in your timing-procedure result is worth considering or if it's OK to ignore it in your individual case. But in terms of “exact” timing, it's undeniable that there will always be this tiny fraction of time wasted by variable assignment included in our result; a minimal timespan that gets times but doesn't actually belong to what we really wanted to time. So, the result will never be 100% exact - because you can't remember something without using a brain. From that point of view, things suddenly start to sound simple… don't they? ;)

Comment: This is actually wrong, you're now measuring the time of 3(!) microtime calls, first the 2 ignores and then the timer_end, so removing ingore_b would make it valid.

Comment: @EaterOfCode Good point... gosh, what was I thinking last summer? Corrected that. Thanks for the heads-up. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! awesome name you have there btw! (yep that was mainly how I got here)

Answer (score 4):

if I were you, I would create a test page..

In that test page I would test for 10 times how much execution time it takes for 2 microtimes and then for 10 times for 1 microtime, and in this way I would find the execution time for one micrtime().

Hope it helps

Comment: *"Hope it helps"* … it did. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (2):** TL;DR

The code below may be modified to print out the overhead.
In that **specific** case that overhead is mostly due to the `microtime()` function itself.

I have measured `microtime()` to require 0.27 us, after an overhead of 0.11 us was removed.

This should answer the question: use the code to measure the overhead, that is what OP was asking for.

---

**EDIT:** to skeptics voting down

The point here is that measuring a *dry* run (the empty `dummy()` function) really removes all the overhead, including such artifacts as the execution of the two `microtime()` calls at the start and end and the `for` loop and everything. But it's nice to see that not everybody gets it, measurement theory really is a complex matter. For those serious about the matter don't get confused by the accepted answer. Better read up some articles on the Internet instead of just looking at StackOverflow.

---

This question is pretty old but I must revive it and answer, because I see a lot of confusion here. The actually true answer is:

> YES YOU CAN, if you know how to actually correctly measure code execution times in general.

This field of **measurement** is pretty complex so I'll try to reduce this exposition as much as possible.

Contrary to the accepted answer, you can actually approach asymptotically the correct value with an error less then epsilon (meaning, as precise as desired).

Let's start slowly: how to avoid interference in a multitasking system.

---

As you maybe know, the kernel of your OS will handle resources. Most notably, the CPU itself. Modern CPUs have a special functionality to quickly switch context ([preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29), [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)).

During measurement, a context switch will inevitably taint your measure, so you'll want to avoid it as much as possible. Under Windows and/or Linux we have different means to mitigate this problem as much as possible, being:

- closing as many applications/daemons/services running concurrently and/or in background as possible;
- detach networks and peripherals like printers (to avoid I/O interrupts);
- use a pure terminal login instead of a graphical interface;
- remove everything else that might interfere.

Then you want to set the priority of the process to real-time so that the round-robin does not preempt a process. But this really depends on the actual kernel in use. There are Linux kernels which are specially compiled with RT in mind. On Windows right-click the application in Task Manager and set priority to the maximum and restrain the process to the second core (the first is *sometimes* preferred by the OS for kernel activities).

Next let's discuss how to avoid paging.

---

Paging is an effect of virtual memory. During execution, some memory pages may be saved into a paging file which resides on disk. The next moment you access a memory address in that page, it will be loaded transparently to the process. The CPU will trap a page-fault exception and activate the loading algorithm. Once the data is loaded into RAM, the process resumes completely unknowingly that a huge amount of time (milliseconds) have passed. In assembler an instruction such as:

```
MOV dest, src
```

will not take 1 CPU cycle as adevertised, but even billions of CPU cycles if *dest* or *src* are paged-out addresses.

To avoid this problem you will have to prefetch all data you will use so that it resides as near to the CPU as possible. The *distance* from the CPU would be:

> PAGEFILE > RAM > L2 CPU CACHE > L1 CPU CACHE > CPU REGISTERS

With PHP this means you can't do that much to solve this problem. In assembler you would have huge optimization leeway in that regard. So, let's say we have to handle this problem in PHP as far as possible without relying on anything outside PHP.

Next, we will discuss noise reduction.

---

The idea of noise reduction is pretty simple. Instead of measuring once, do many measurements and then average across all values. This way the fluctuation of the single errors will be removed and only a hard *base error* will remain.

This means you'll measure in a cycle and over many instances, then average the cumulative value.

Next, we will discuss how to remove overhead, which apparently leads to much confusion.

---

If you measure an algorithm there will be inevitably additional instructions needed to get it going. But you don't really want to measure those, you just want to measure the *gist* of what you intend. The additional measurement is an *overhead* that must be removed from the actual measurement. Under lucky circumstances (which is our case, here) the above *base error* will still be present while the auxiliary code is under execution, and if you are good at measurements, you'll even have a chance on removing it completely, obtaining a pretty precise result.

Now let's wrap it all up and see not just example code but actual code that implements all those concepts. The comments in the code will point to the things said so far.

```
<?php

$dummy = function ()
{
    // don't do anything
};

$f = function ()
{
    microtime(true);
};

function measure($callback, $repetitions)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) // prefetch
    {
        $callback();
    }

    $us = -microtime(true);
    for($i = 0; $i < $repetitions; $i++)
    {
        $callback();
    }
    $us += microtime(true);

    return $us;
}

$retries = 10;
$repetitions = 100000; // may be higher/lower depending on necessity

while ($retries-- > 0)
{
    sleep(5);

    $ovrh = measure($dummy, $repetitions); // measure overhead, including function calls and everything...
    $time = measure($f, $repetitions);

    echo 'ovrh: ' . $ovrh / $repetitions . "\n";           // it's important you only divide in the end,
    echo 'time: ' . ($time - $ovrh) / $repetitions . "\n"; // after computing the difference!
}
```

So, this should run pretty well for a minute or two, but I don't actually know because I've never run it. If there are typos and stuff it's because of this.

What you will do now is run this while there is no other interference. As the numbers are printed out the pauses allow the system to eventually recover from interference. You'll have to retry it many times (10 in the code above) because you'll have to watch it closely:

> If the resulting numbers are always the same than that's the value you want!
>
> If the numbers jump up and down then there's a problem and the measurement does not work.

At your leisure you want to substitute the code in `f()` as you wish. Remember that the `dummy()` must also contain the auxiliary code.

Example: you have `f()` with an assignment as auxiliary code that you can't remove.

```
public function f()
{
    $v = 3 * 4; // the assignment is auxiliary but cannot be removed
                // note that the compiler may optimize the multiplication
                // into the resulting number 12
                // in that case execution time will be very near to the
                // overhead and the difference will be 0 or, because of
                // errors, by chance be less than 0!
}

public function dummy()
{
    $v = 0; // this is the code you want to measure as overhead
}
```

Under circumstance it is possible to write the `dummy()` function so that the overhead is correctly measured and removed. In some cases this is not entirely possible, but explaining which algorithms fall under this category is another story :)

Finally remember this:

> WHAT do you want to measure? Purely ideal execution times or real-life realistic execution times?
>
> In this second case, which is far more interesting and useful, you will have to put the code on the production server and run it WITH all the interference and concurrency from the OS.

---

I've just fixed a typo and some errors due to the habit of writing object-oriented code and not scripts. The above script should now run without errors from a Linux command line and probably on Windows as well.

I've measured 2.7 * 10^-7 seconds, while running a youtube video in gnome and with chrome and some other windows open. That's 0.27 microseconds. The actual results printed out are:

```
2.7603149414062E-7
2.7155160903931E-7
2.670693397522E-7
2.7152061462402E-7
2.7000188827515E-7
2.705192565918E-7
2.7431011199951E-7
2.7279138565063E-7
2.6989936828613E-7
2.7417182922363E-7
```

As we can see, it is relatively stable, so we can assume there is no measuring error due to paging or sporadic I/O interrupts. Context switching and continuous network traffic still have an impact, but I would consider it *normal circumstances* that have to be taken into account. Nobody would run a program in total isolation. It would be a nice theoretical exercise but of no real-life value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need a loop to iterate the call and then divide it with the number of times to know an average time for each, by example

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) microtime(TRUE);
```

And another for a single loop:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++);
```

save these file into testmicrotime.php and testloop.php respectivelly and then, (linux) do:

```
$> time php testmicrotime.php
```

Then you need to substract the time used for just do the loop:

```
$> time php testloop.php
```

I got user time of 2.056s and 0.512s, so that's 1.544 / 100000 = 0.00001544s or 15.44 microseconds each call.

Of course to make it a more reliable metric you need to run this many times to obtain an average, and this can change dramatically depending on your CPU clock and speed.

Comment: Braceless `if` in PHP? That was a bad idea when C invented it, and had not improved by the time it turned up in PHP. Its use here is easily worth a downvote.

Comment: @AaronMiller 1. there isn't any `if` in this answer 2. It's not worth a downvote if someone doesn't follow YOUR coding standards, because its yours not his

Comment: @AaronMiller We are not discussing coding standards here